# Intellij IDEA link to static file in jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

our project structure is as follow:

```
  -webapp  
     -static
        -js
```

And we use this of spring to define the static file url rule:

```
<mvc:resources location="/static/js/" mapping="/js/**"/>
```

so, we use something like this to link to static file:

```
<script src="<%=path%>/js/index.js"></script>
```

now, we can't jump to `index.js` file by clicking or shortcut by pressing the combination `ctrl+shift+b`.

but if our structure is like this:

```
  -webapp  
     -js
```

we are able to jump to `index.js` file.

some one know how to solve it? thanks.

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Have you had a look to this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-static-content-resources.html

Comment: thanks.you are right.